# Application Loader Error

Tags: xcode, api, loader, ipa

I am trying to submit my app.ipa to application loader but when i press there is a error

We’re having trouble connecting to the App Store. Please try again later.

You are not authorized to use this service.

Answer (score 2):

You might have changed the password for your developer account. Just sign in again with correct password, then this error should go away. (I saw exactly the same error today and after I signed in with the updated password, it is fine now.)